# Mi web.config se borra al compilar

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, backend

Me pasaron un proyecto en MVC5 C# ASP.NET para que lo siguiera desarrollando, y me ocurre algo que no se porque pasa, si añado una key o una connectionstring en el web.config y compilo el proyecto, este regresa a como cuando me lo entregaron, es decir el web.config se restaura a su punto inicial, ¿Como se arregla esto?

Comment: puedes colocar codigo? donde lee tu web.config, que método realiza cambios en el web.config?

Answer (score 0):

Ya logré solucionarlo, el proyecto venia con un archivo llamada "web.base.config", y este era el web.config "real", gracias por la ayuda.